# Next.js: Passing props from layout.jsx into another path in the App folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm using Next.js 13 and I want to pass a props from a client side rendering operation in the layout.jsx directly to a page.jsx that's in another folder called general. All of this, of course, in the app folder, so I want this to be passed to another route. For example: from localhost:3000 to localhost:3000/general.

I don't know how to do it. I have the next code:

```js
'use client';

import React, { Children, useState } from 'react';
import HeaderContent from '@components/HeaderContent';
import LeftSidebar from '@components/LeftSidebar';
import PathSearchSection from '@components/PathSearchSection';
import BlankProjectModal from '@components/modals/BlankProjectModal';
import ToDoListModal from '@components/ToDoListModal';
import TemplatesModal from '@components/TemplateModal';
import './styles/main.css';

export const metadata = {
    title: "LOl",
    description: "LOL"
}

function Layout({ children }) {
    const [bpModalOpen, setBpModalOpen] = useState(false);

    const createBlankProject=(isOpen)=> {
        setBpModalOpen(isOpen);
    }

    const [tempModalOpen, setTempModalOpen] = useState(false); 

    const createTemplate = (isOpen) => {
        setTempModalOpen(isOpen);
    }

    const [tdlModalOpen, setTdlModalOpen] = useState(false);

    const ToggleTdlModal=(isOpen)=> {
        setTdlModalOpen(isOpen);
    }

    const [docIndex, setDocIndex] = useState(0);

    const newCreatedDocIndex=(index)=> {
        setDocIndex(index);
    }

    const [nameValue, setNameValue] = useState("");

    function setNewDocName(newName){
        setNameValue(newName)
    }
    return (
        <html>
            <head>
                {/* <!-- Font Awesome --> */}
                <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
                {/* <!-- Google Fonts --> */}
                <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;300&family=Jost:wght@100;300&family=Roboto+Flex:wght@100&family=Space+Grotesk&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>
                <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
                {/* <!-- MDB -->  */}
                <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdb-ui-kit/6.0.1/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
                {/* <!-- MDB -->  */}
                <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdb-ui-kit/6.0.1/mdb.min.js"></script>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css" />
                <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet" />
            </head>
            <body className="App">
                {/* Blank Project Modal */}
                <div className='blankproject-modal-container' style={{ display: bpModalOpen ? 'flex' : 'none' }}>
                    <BlankProjectModal currentDocIndex={docIndex} isOpen={createBlankProject} newDoc={newCreatedDocIndex} newDocName={setNewDocName}/>
                </div>

                {/* Template Modal */}
                <div className='template-modal-container' style={{ display: tempModalOpen ? 'flex' : 'none' }}>
                    <TemplatesModal currentDocIndex={docIndex} isOpen={createTemplate} newDoc={newCreatedDocIndex} newDocName={setNewDocName}/>
                </div>
                
                {/* To-Do List Project Modal */}
                <div className='todolist-modal-container' style={{ display: tdlModalOpen ? 'flex' : 'none' }}>
                    <ToDoListModal isOpen={ToggleTdlModal}/>
                </div>
                {/* Header */}
                <HeaderContent/>
                <main style={{display: 'flex' }}>
                    <div className="left-bar-container" style={{height: 'calc(100vh-75px)' }}>
                        <LeftSidebar createBP={createBlankProject} createTemp={createTemplate}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="main-container" style={{ width: 'calc(100% - 252px)'}}>
                        <div className="main-content" style={{ flex: '1'}}>
                            <PathSearchSection/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="main-content" style={{ flex: '1'}}>
                            {children}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </main>
            </body>
        </html>
    )
}

export default CampusCloudLayout
```

I don't know how to pass it from the { children } to an specific route, because I have like 5 different routes in the app. In this case, I want to pass some props to the general folder.

Comment: did you try using a [Context](https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext#passing-data-deeply-into-the-tree) ?